# "like a duck takes to water" vs "like a fish takes to water"

Tags: idioms

I am aware of the idiom *like a fish **out** of water*. What intrigued me is an article using *like a fish takes to water*.

> Teo Zhen Ren, the swimming sensation from Singapore, took to swimming like a fish takes to water.

Is *like a fish takes to water* a valid usage? Is it an idiom? I thought the usual phrase was *like a **duck** takes to water*.

Comment: It's a valid usage, but it's out of tune; it sounds like it was composed by a non-native English speaker. Fish don't _take to_ water, any more than humans _take to_ air. _Take to `X`_ is an idiom that means 'adapt to a new `X` environment'. Fish live in water by definition; nothing new.

Comment: Please don't quote articles without saying what you're quoting.

Comment: I think the phrase you read is a compounded malapropism of *Like fish out of water* and *Like duck takes to water*. If you have the opportunity, you should write to the editorial contact of the article to point out their misconception.

Comment: I think ELU needs this question [*like a duck needs a bicycle.*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22duck+needs+a+bicycle%22&oq=%22duck+needs+a+bicycle%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.2979j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @TRiG: I disagree. In this case, the particular source of the quote is totally irrelevant, and linking to it could be seen as impolite: it would be the internet equivalent of pointing and laughing.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I disagree that it is "not quite right." The writer is presumably inverting (or otherwise altering) the trope, which is certainly fair game. He means to disturb your ear, which is why you find it odd.

Comment: Said the fish to the duck: “Ah you think water is your ally? You merely adopted the wet. I was born in it, molded by it. I didn't see the air until I was already a smolt, by then it was nothing to me but suffocating!”

Comment: @Fumble Interesting. I don't know if this was the point of your phrasing/link, but I've only ever heard “like a _fish_ needs a bicycle”. More mixing up of ducks and fishes. Also, “like a fish without a bicycle”.

Comment: @Janus: I should have added a smiley! :) Yes, I was deliberately mixing my metaphors to reflect what Blessed Geek calls "compounded malapropism" in the original. Without detailed knowledge of the context, we can't know for sure if it's deliberate or not, but it certainly *sounds* like a non-native speaker "error" to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Like a duck takes to water* is a well known idiom, and has references in appropriate reference materials (e.g. books on idioms). Here, that and more [*duck idioms*](http://www.word-detective.com/2013/01/out-for-a-duck/) are discussed. As you've stated, it means *easily*.

However, googling *like a fish takes to water* gets many hits, where it's used exactly like *like a duck takes to water*. However, they are blog sites; there are no idiom explanations.

I suspect people use it because mixing of metaphors occurred somewhere along the line.

Fish idioms include:
*like a fish out of water*, *swims like a fish*, *drinks like a fish*, and others.

Comment: People take to mixed metaphors like a fish takes to mixed metaphors.

Comment: @BrianDHall You mean, with little to no comprehension?

Comment: Yes, ignorantly.

Answer (score 5):

> Like a fish takes to water

is valid, but not right. The "took to water" part suggests they weren't always in the water. Better (I believe) is:

> He took to [his new job / skiing / living in Spain / other activity] like a duck to water.

However, your particular example is essentially the only place your phrase is used - when that activity is swimming.

Comment: "your example is the only place it is used" - when *what* is used?

Comment: I disagree that it is "not quite right." The writer is presumably inverting the trope, which is fair game.

Comment: It isn't "not quite right". It is "quite wrong".  A duck is born on land, but instinctively know how to swim: it "takes" to water.  A fish is in water its whole life -- except perhaps the very end.

Answer (score 4):

The correct idiom is "*[Take to something like a duck to water](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+to+like+a+duck+to+water)*": (from TFD)

> to learn how to do something very quickly and to enjoy doing it
>        *Sue just took to motherhood like a duck to water.*
>        *He's taken to his new school like a duck to water.*

Like a fish takes to water appears to be a variant of the original saying.

Answer (score 2):

I am a non-native speaker and I frequently hear such idiomatic constructions.
Probably, the writer **assumed** that since both *duck and fish* take to water equally, they could be interchanged.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me more likely that the intended *fish/water* reference above is to the expression "like a fish in water," as in this quotation from a [letter by Daniel Baker](http://books.google.com/books?id=XgZMAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA344&dq=%22like+a+fish+in+water%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=238sVP6NJ-TCigLFlYDIAQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22like%20a%20fish%20in%20water%22&f=false), from Port Lavaca, Texas, on June 26, 1848, reprinted in *The Life and Labours of the Rev. Daniel Baker D.D.: Pastor and Evangelist* (1858):

> O, it is pleasant to preach to a people who seem to be so eager to hear the word of life. It rouses me delightfully, and I feel as if I was in my own native element ; or, as the saying is, **like a fish in water**. I do believe I was cut out for a missionary — no mistake.